# how to retrieve multiple properties of selected list object from struts2 select tag through list key?

Tags: select, struts2

I have a list of objects in struts2 select tag. i want to retrieve the selected list object, not just id or any property as none of them or unique property, is there any way to get whole object? my code goes as below   i want to retrieve all the fields, name,id,date,cba, seq.. as none of them are unique fields, i can not just get the id, then get the other fields from database.

any help???

```
<s:select name="appls" list="applList" id="appls"
          listKey="id"
          listValue="%{enroller.name.fullName + '-' + enroller.cba+'......' + openDateStr + '.....' + seq}"
          multiple="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean, "get the whole object" or "retrieve the list object"?

In any case, IMO you should build complicated option labels in Java, not in the view.

`listValue` can be an arbitrary OGNL expression, using the same value stack as the page itself, plus each of the select's list items pushed onto the top. Without knowing more about what you're actually trying to do, it's difficult to help much beyond that.

Comment: yes Dave, i want to retrieve the selected list object..

I want to get the all properties of that object to my acton class.

Comment: @user1491334 Repeating it doesn't help. All you can send from HTML is an id or strings that can be type-converted.